# Java remove listener from button after 3 clicks

Tags: java, swing, button, action, listener

So I want to remove a listener from a button after the button has been pressed 3 times.
So far I have this

```
class Q5 
{
JFrame frame;
JButton button;
int clickCount = 0;

public static void main (String[] args)
{
    Q5 example = new Q5();
    example.go();
}

public void go()
{
    frame = new JFrame();

    button = new JButton ("Should I do it");
    button.addActionListener(new ButtonPressListener());
    button.addActionListener(new AngelListener());
    button.addActionListener(new DevilListener());
    button.addActionListener(new ConfusedListener());



    frame.getContentPane().add(BorderLayout.CENTER, button);
    frame.setVisible(true);
    frame.setSize(400,150);
    // set frame properties here
}

class ButtonPressListener implements ActionListener 
{
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) 
    {
        clickCount++;
    }
}

class AngelListener implements ActionListener 
{
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) 
    {
        System.out.println("Don't do it, you might regret it!");
    }
}

class DevilListener implements ActionListener 
{
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) 
    {
        System.out.println("Go on, do it!");
    }
}

class ConfusedListener implements ActionListener   
{
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) 
    {
        if(clickCount > 3)
        {
            for(ConfusedListener conf : button.getActionListeners())
            {
                button.removeActionListener(conf);
            }
        }
        else
            System.out.println("I don't know!");
    }
}
```

The way I read online was do a for loop, as I tried above, however I get a type mismatch. Most of the examples I could find were about removing all of the listeners, however I only want to remove the ConfusedListener from the button. Other than the for loop above, I don't have any ideas of how to do it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `getActionListeners()` method returns all the listeners of the button. And they're not all instances of `ConfusedListener`. The only sure thing we know is that they're instances of `ActionListener`. That's why your code doesn't compile.

Now, why would you need a loop to remove a given listener? You simply need to remove the ConfusedListener that is being invoked. So you just need

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) 
{
    if(clickCount > 3)
    {
        button.removeActionListener(this);
    }
    else
        System.out.println("I don't know!");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could try:

```
if(clickCount > 3)
    {
        for(ActionListener listener : button.getActionListeners())
        {
            if (listener instanceOf ConfusedListener) {
                button.removeActionListener(conf);
            }
        }
    }
    else
        System.out.println("I don't know!");
```

You could also save the instance of the ConfusedListener when adding it and remove it via

```
button.removeActionListener(confusedListenerInstance);
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer however the accepted answer worked great :)

Answer (score 1):

Just store an instance of the listener itself and use it to remove the correct listener:

```
final ConfusedListener confusedListener = new ConfusedListener();
button.addActionListener(confusedListener);
button.removeActionListener(confusedListener);
```

Of if you are removing the listener from inside a method of `ConfusedListener` itself just pass `this`:

```
button.removeActionListener(this);
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply however the accepted answer worked great :)